# change opacity of one div by hovering over another div

Tags: css, hover

I have a problem. I made a custom html5 soundcloud player and I have a playlist with images. I want to display the title of the image by hovering over the image.

for example I made a simple jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dC85Q/

At the moment the opacity only changes when I hove over the title div. But it should change when i hove over the image div. I know its possible with javascript but I dont want to use javascript for that. Is there a way to do it with css?

my html:

```
<div id="song1" class="songs" onclick="song1()">
    <div id="songtitle1" class="songtitles">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

Comment: realy? thats anoying. then i have to use javascript

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `:hover` pseudo selector on `.songs`, but then target `.songtitles` and change its opacity:

```
.songs:hover .songtitles {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dC85Q/1/)

Comment: It doesn't work!